# Implementing a Doubly Linked List from a Sorted Array Bag (Data Structures)

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

it's my first time ever posting on StackOverFlow, because I'm truly desperate right now. I couldn't find an answer for my problem anywhere, so long story short, I have some kind of project for my Data Structures course. The project had 2 parts. The first part was implementing a Sorted Array Bag/ Sorted Collection for some problem. We are using **java**.

The second part is where I do actually have a lot of problems. So the main idea is implementing a doubly-linked list from the sorted-array bag/ sorted collection and in a way that I would just switch sorted array bag with doubly-linked list in my main and everything should work the way it was working before.

The main thing about the SortedArrayBag is as far as I understand using a Comparator when you declare the SortedArrayBag in your main, and it looks like this:

```
SortedBag<Grupe> al = new SortedArrayBag<>(new ComparatorVot());
al.add(new Grupe("gr1", 5));
al.add(new Grupe("gr2", 7));
```

The sorted collection/sorted array bag was implemented by my teacher because there is no such data structure in Java, here is her implementation:

```
public class SortedArrayBag<T> implements SortedBag<T> {

    private ArrayList<T> elemente;
    private Comparator<T> relatie;

    public SortedArrayBag(Comparator<T> rel) {
        this.elemente = new ArrayList<>();
        this.relatie = rel;
    }

    public void add(T elem) {
        int index = 0;
        boolean added = false;
        while (index < this.elemente.size() && added == false) {
            T currentElem = this.elemente.get(index);
            if (relatie.compare(currentElem, elem) < 0) {
                index++;
            } else {
                this.elemente.add(index, elem);
                added = true;
            }
        }
        if (!added) {
            this.elemente.add(elem);
        }
    }

    public void remove(T elem) {
        boolean removed = this.elemente.remove(elem);
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.elemente.size();
    }

    public boolean search(T elem) {
        return this.elemente.contains(elem);
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return this.elemente.iterator();
    }

}
```

And the SortedBag interface looks like this

```
public interface SortedBag<T> {
    public void add(T elem);
    public void remove(T elem);
    public int size();
    public boolean search(T elem);
    public Iterator<T> iterator();
}
```

Also in case it helps, the comparator looks like this:

```
public class ComparatorVot implements Comparator<Grupe> {


    public int compare(Grupe o1, Grupe o2) {
        Grupe gr1 = (Grupe) o1;
        Grupe gr2 = (Grupe) o2;


        if (gr1.getNrPersoane() / 2 + 1 == gr2.getNrPersoane() / 2 + 1) {
            return 0;
        } else if (gr1.getNrPersoane() / 2 + 1 > gr2.getNrPersoane() / 2 + 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

So, I tried my best implementing doublyLinkedList using a SortedArrayBag, this is what I did, also if it helps making my code more clear, prim=first, ultim=last, urmator=next, anterior=previous

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class LDI {
    private Nod prim;
    private Nod ultim;

//private int lungime;
public LDI() {
    this.prim = null;
    this.ultim = null;
    //this.lungime = 0;
}

public class Nod {
    private int elem;
    private int frecventa;
    private Nod urmator;
    private Nod anterior;

    public Nod(int e, int f) {
        this.elem = e;
        this.frecventa = f;
        this.urmator = null;
        this.anterior = null;
    }
}

public void add(int elem, int frecventa) {
    Nod nodNou = new Nod(elem, frecventa);
    nodNou.elem = elem;
    nodNou.frecventa = frecventa;
    if (prim == null) {
        this.prim = nodNou;
        this.ultim = nodNou;
    } else if (frecventa <= prim.frecventa) {
        nodNou.urmator = prim;
        this.prim.anterior = nodNou;
        this.prim = nodNou;
    } else if (frecventa >= prim.frecventa) {
        nodNou.anterior = prim;
        for (; nodNou.anterior.urmator != null; nodNou.anterior = nodNou.anterior.urmator) {
            if (nodNou.anterior.urmator.frecventa > frecventa)
                break;
        }
        nodNou.urmator = nodNou.anterior.urmator;
        if (nodNou.anterior.urmator != null) {
            nodNou.anterior.urmator.anterior = nodNou;
        }
        nodNou.anterior.urmator = nodNou;
        nodNou.anterior = nodNou.anterior;
    }
}


public void remove() {
    if (this.prim != null) {
        if (this.prim == this.ultim) {
            this.prim = null;
            this.ultim = null;
        } else
            this.prim = this.prim.urmator;
        this.prim.anterior = null;
    }
}

public int size() {
    int count = 0;
    for (Nod nodNou = prim; nodNou != null; nodNou = nodNou.urmator)
        count++;
    return count;
}

public class MyIterator {
    private Nod curent;

    public MyIterator() {
        this.curent = prim;
    }

    public void urmator() {
        this.curent = this.curent.urmator;
    }

    public int getElem() {
        return this.curent.elem;
    }

    public boolean valid() {
        if (this.curent != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public Iterator iterator() {
    return new MyIterator();
}
}
```

The thing is, it doesn't work, I have no idea how to make my data structure able to receive the Comparator I used and also the Iterator doesn't work. If you have any idea how to make this work, please do help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  First, thanks for putting some effort into your question.  Unfortunately, _"it doesn't work"_ isn't a sufficient description of the problem.  From your code it is clear you are missing some fundamental concepts to do with generics and how to use them.  Your data structure should be generic `public class LDI <T> { ...` in order to use the underlying `SortedArrayBag<T>` provided by your teacher.  At this point it is time to review the textbook and class notes, and go talk to your professor.  There is not room here to build up all the concepts you need to learn...

Comment: ... and also that is not the purpose of StackOverflow.  I suggest you visit the [help] and read [ask] for details.

Comment: Thank you for your time, it's actually the first time I hear about generics, I only started learning coding seriously just over a month ago and now I have this homework that I have no idea how to solve and I'm kind of desperate, because it's a project that will define if I will pass or fail the exam, even though we didn't have something like this presented in the classroom. That's why I am desperate and I decided to try to ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: There's something seriously wrong if you're supposed to do work that wasn't covered in class and in the text, unless it was a prerequisite for the course.  At this time the only possible way forward is to talk to your professor.